# Transfer larger file using WCF service with basichttpbinding

Tags: wcf, binding, large-files, file-transfer

I'm getting below error when I try to transfer more than 150MB files.

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException was unhandled
  Message="An error occurred while making the HTTP request to http://localhost:2122/Service1.svc. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server."
  Source="mscorlib"
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at Cleint.ServiceReference1.IService1.UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request)
       at Cleint.ServiceReference1.Service1Client.Cleint.ServiceReference1.IService1.UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request) in D:\MCT_Work\Sample Projects\WCFFileTransferTest\Cleint\Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.cs:line 81
       at Cleint.ServiceReference1.Service1Client.UploadFile(String fileName, Stream fileByteStream) in D:\MCT_Work\Sample Projects\WCFFileTransferTest\Cleint\Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.cs:line 88
       at Cleint.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\MCT_Work\Sample Projects\WCFFileTransferTest\Cleint\Program.cs:line 20
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       Message="The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."
       Source="System"
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
       InnerException: System.IO.IOException
            Message="Unable to write data to the transport connection: An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full."
            Source="System"
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.MultipleWrite(BufferOffsetSize[] buffers)
                 at System.Net.Connection.Write(ScatterGatherBuffers writeBuffer)
                 at System.Net.ConnectStream.ResubmitWrite(ConnectStream oldStream, Boolean suppressWrite)
            InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
                 Message="An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full"
                 Source="System"
                 ErrorCode=10055
                 NativeErrorCode=10055
                 StackTrace:
                      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.MultipleSend(BufferOffsetSize[] buffers, SocketFlags socketFlags)
                      at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.MultipleWrite(BufferOffsetSize[] buffers)
                 InnerException:
```

Comment: Does it work fine for smaller files? Can you show the binding configuration is your web.config and app.config ?

Comment: There is an internal error saying there is not enough buffer space. Just check that you are not running out of memory?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `transferMode` is **buffer**, so the large messages are bufferred in memory. If you've access to change Service destination (code), I'd suggest to use transfer mode **Streaming** or **MTOM** message encoding to exchange such a large messages/files.

Comment: This worked out perfect - was getting *"Unable to write data to the transport connection: An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full"*. Using `transferMode="Streamed"` in the `binding` element fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to transmit 150MB across a web service boundary? This design will almost certainly cause you availability issues on the service endpoint.

A better design would be to write the file to disk somewhere, and then send a command message to the service to pick up the file.

Comment: I have got solution by delpoying the same solution in IIS, that works great, I tried to transfer 1GB file it worked.